# How to create a server in MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm just a beginner and I want to know how to create a server in MS SQL 2005 because I want to use MS SQL as my database for a vb.net database program.

I'm only using a single desktop computer. What would you recommend? This will only be used as a database for a vb.net program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a single computer and a single program, then you should consider SQL Server Express instead. This page has info about the 2008 version: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

If you're beginning, consider whether you should begin with something other than VB.net.  Is there a specific reason for using it?  It could be a great opportunity to learn Visual C# or similar.

Comment: Even express edition is probably overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, get into some VB.NET tutorials (as in: everyone that is not totally trivial has some section about databases).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm only using a single desktop computer.

I'd recommend going with an *in-process* or desktop engine rather than a server-class engine like sql server.  Even Sql Server Express Edition is usually overkill.  Use something like Sql Server Compact Edition, Sqlite, or even Access instead.